# Unable to update position in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to update position in core data base. When I add object or remove it from that base everything works fine. Problem occurs when I want to update object in that base. The problem is that program throws me:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCES(code = 2, adres = 0x38)`.

It's weird because it throws this error but updtades object at core data. I'm using simulator on Xcode 5. I've tried to comment line by line back in code but it hasn't helped anymore. Taking look at the address of the error and the screen shot there is no address compatible with each other. What is wrong?

Code is this:

```
[self insertPositionRightAfterChangeValues:name rating:[changedRate stringValue] urlMain:[newInsert urlMain] contentUrl:[newInsert contentUrl] coverUrl:[newInsert coverUrl] date:[newInsert date] type:[newInsert type] int:integer];
```

And the rest of this method:

```
-(void)insertPositionRightAfterChangeValues:(NSString *)name rating:(NSString *)rating urlMain:(NSString *)urlMain contentUrl:(NSString *)contentUrl coverUrl:(NSString *)coverUrl date:(NSString *)date type:(NSString *)type int:(int)position
{
    int motherPosision = position;

    //insert new one
    NSManagedObjectContext *context2 = [self managedObjectContext];
    Kwejki * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kwejki" inManagedObjectContext:context2];

    newEntry.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: name];
    newEntry.rating = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: rating];
    newEntry.urlMain = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: urlMain];
    newEntry.contentUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: contentUrl];
    newEntry.coverUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: coverUrl];
    newEntry.date = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: date];
    newEntry.type = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: type];


    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.name);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.rating);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.urlMain);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.contentUrl);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.coverUrl);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.date);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.type);

    NSError *error2;
    if (![context2 save:&error2]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"SAVED!!!");
    }

}
```

And the screenshot with this error:

[image]

UPDATE:

When I comment line where I invoke method to insert new object I get following error: `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Kwejki'`

UPDATE 2:

```
@interface Kwejki : NSManagedObject<NSCopying>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * contentUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * coverUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * rating;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * urlMain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;

@end


@implementation Kwejki

@synthesize name;
@synthesize date;
@synthesize urlMain;
@synthesize rating;
@synthesize coverUrl;
@synthesize contentUrl;
@synthesize type;

-(Kwejki *)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Kwejki *copyModel = [[Kwejki allocWithZone:zone] init];

    if(copyModel)
    {
        copyModel.name = [self name];
        copyModel.date = [self date];
        copyModel.urlMain = [self urlMain];
        copyModel.rating = [self rating];
        copyModel.coverUrl = [self coverUrl];
        copyModel.contentUrl = [self contentUrl];
        copyModel.type = [self type];
    }
    return  copyModel;
}


@end



-(void)addNewPosition:(ScrollViewViewController *)ScrollController recentlyDownloadedItem:(KwejkModel *)modelTmp
{

    if(modelTmp == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES NULL");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not null");
    }


    Kwejki * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kwejki" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"%@", [modelTmp getNameOfItem]);

    newEntry.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[modelTmp getNameOfItem]];
    newEntry.rating = [modelTmp getRateOfPosition];
    newEntry.urlMain = [modelTmp getUrlAdress];
    newEntry.contentUrl = [modelTmp getContentUrl];
    newEntry.coverUrl = [modelTmp getCoverImage];
    newEntry.date = [modelTmp getDateOfItem];

    if([modelTmp getType] == photo)
    {
        newEntry.type = @"0";

    }
    else if([modelTmp getType] == gif)
    {
        newEntry.type = @"1";

    }
    else if ([modelTmp getType] == video)
    {
        newEntry.type = @"2";

    }


    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.name);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.rating);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.urlMain);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.contentUrl);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.coverUrl);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.date);
    NSLog(@"%@", newEntry.type);

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"UDALO SIE!!!");
    }
    [modelArray insertObject:newEntry atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

I've tried to overcome this problem just adding new object again as update but it also doesn't helped. How I add new object: I tap long on position, new window opens and there I add new values, invoke from that view method from Main ViewController, and here it crashes. When I add normally object as described above but in separate window everything works. I really don't know what is wrong.

Comment: How does the screenshot relate to the code in the question? It looks like a recursive call based on the screenshot. Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Hi @Wain. How do you see that it is recursive?

Comment: iOS does code but then pause and stops again where I invoke method to update.

Comment: @DKM, Can you share how you defined properties in `Kwejki` class? I am particularly interested in properties that you've used as parameters to call `insertPositionRightAfterChangeValues`.

Comment: You say your problem comes when you try to update an object in your database, but the code you posted is adding a new object, not updating an old one. Also, in the code you show, all those "[NSString alloc] initWithString:..." lines are unnecessary. You're already passing in strings, you don't need to create new ones; newEntry.name = name; etc. is sufficient.

Comment: Where are you calling copy? You can't do that with a managed object. At least not the way you have implemented it.

Comment: You can't effectively implement NSCopying on a managed object. A managed object context have to observe the life cycle of a managed object, which is (almost) impossible to do within the contract of NSCopying.

Comment: When I call this like:  Kwejki *newInsert = [[self.modelArray objectAtIndex:integer] copy]; I got message that: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Kwejki'

Comment: Instead of this how to make copy of object.....just assigning properties to new object?

Comment: Yes you're right! The problem was in NSCOPYING protocol. Thank you very much for that comment @Wain and quellish

Answer (score 1):

When I see this error it normally mean that I did not setup my NSManageObject correctly.

Things to check:

1. Add a break point in your insertPositionRightAfterChangeValues method and step through to find where the exception is thrown.  (My guess is when your creating your Kwejki object.)
2. That Kwejki is a subclass of NSManageObject.
3. That Kwejki entity and class name are correct.  (Could you show your .xcdatamodeId entity properties for Kwejki?)

If everything is correct, then for an insanity check I would create the Kwejki object the long way.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Kwejki class]) inManagedObjectContext:context2];
Kwejki* newEntry = [[Kwejki alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context2];
```

Then you can see if the entity is a problem or your Kwejki is.

P.S. As a helpful suggestion instead of typing in the entity name.

```
Kwejki * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kwejki" inManagedObjectContext:context2];
```

I would do something like this.

```
Kwejki * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Kwejki class]) inManagedObjectContext:context2];
```

This give you a compiler check for entity name.

Comment: I've made mistake in coping object that can not be copied normally using NSCOPYING protocol